# Just get entire response to request

Tags: curl

I want to see exactly what my web server is sending. I don't want to parse the headers or get opinions about the validity of the response. I just want to see the raw response itself.

When I use curl to send a response to my web server, it says this:

```
# curl https://my.web.site/
curl: (1) Unsupported HTTP version in response
```

I get that my server's response is sending some kind of unsupported version. How can I see what is actually being sent, so I can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `curl -I`?

Comment: Or `curl -v ...`?

Comment: curl -I gives the same response

curl -v is giviing me more information. I'll post it in an edit to my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the answer to my question is that that actually is what my server was sending. My confusion was that the response is from nginx, which is complaining about the response the reverse proxy was sending. So now I need to know how to get that response, but at least I'm making progress.